# How to only allow existing users from a MS database to login

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

How would I be able to only allow existing users from a MS access database to login. I have a MS database and the 3 attributes "AccountID", "Username" and "Password"

My database: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ahmed\OneDrive\Desktop\ProjectDatabase.accdb

```
Private Sub Loginbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Loginbtn.Click
    If Usernamebtn.Text = "Admin" AndAlso Passwordbtn.Text = "code" Then
        MsgBox("You are Logged In!", MessageBoxIcon.Information, "Login")
        AppMenu.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    ElseIf Usernamebtn.Text = "" OrElse Passwordbtn.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Fill in the Username and Password!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    Else
        If Usernamebtn.Text = My.Settings.Username AndAlso Passwordbtn.Text = My.Settings.Password Then
            MsgBox("You are Logged In!", MessageBoxIcon.Information, "Login")
            AppMenu.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MsgBox("User dosen't exist OR password incorrect, Please try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? What happens - error message, wrong result, nothing?

Comment: Are you asking how to query the DB to authenticate users rather than using the app settings?

Comment: If you're planning to hard code the admin password, I would advise you to rethink that decision.

Comment: Have you added the appropriate settings to each user's computer? I think what you need is a Table in your database that contains the user names and passwords. Query the database to see if the user has entered an existing name and password match.

Comment: It creates the user and i can login but when i end the app it forgets and I have to create it again.

Comment: If your problem has been solved, so please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

You should save user information in database. Every time a user logs in, it's information will be compared with the data in database.
Here's an simple example you can refer to.

Design view of my table:

[image]

Code:

```
Private connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= your file path;"
Private Sub Loginbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Loginbtn.Click
    Using conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connString)
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmdTxt As String = "SELECT password FROM UserTable WHERE username = @username"
        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(cmdTxt, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", UsernameTxt.Text)
            Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If reader.HasRows Then
                While reader.Read
                    Dim pwd As String = reader(0).ToString
                    If PasswordTxt.Text.Equals(pwd) Then
                        MsgBox("You are Logged In!", MessageBoxIcon.Information, "Login")
                    Else
                        MsgBox("Your username or password is incorrect, Please try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
                    End If
                End While
            Else
                MsgBox("Your username or password is incorrect, Please try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```